# How to calculate quartiles in Python without import

Tags: python, math, quartile

I have a school prodject were we need to calculate the quartiles of a list (list should be able to be both an even and an uneven list) in python. I am not allowed to use import (exept math.floor/math.ceil) to make things easier. I just can't get it to work though because I sometimes get a value thats plus or minus 0.5. (so if i wanted 3 for an example i get 2.5 or 3.5 depending on the combination and amount of numbers in the list)
Any suggestions?

The code i have thus far looks like this:

```
def quartile_one(x):
    x.sort()
    k = 0
    if (len(x)%2) == 0:
        k = (math.floor((len(x) + 1)*0.25))
        return ((x[k - 1]) + (x[k]))/2
    else:
        k = (math.floor((len(x) + 1)*0.25))
        return x[k - 1]

def quartile_three(x):
    x.sort()
    k = 0
    if (len(x)%2) == 0:
        k = (math.floor(len(x)*0.75))
        return (((x[k - 1]) + (x[k]))/2)
    else:
        k = (math.floor(len(x)*0.75))
        return x[k - 1]

x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

print(quartile_one(x))
print(quartile_three(x))
```

(expected output: 2.5 and 7.5)

Thanks!

Sorry for any bad grammar.

Comment: "I just can't get it to work" Please [edit] to describe exactly _how_ it doesn;t work. Do you get an error? If so, please include the full error traceback. A wrong output? please give the current output and the expected output and describe how they're different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the 1st and 3rd quartiles do not depend on N/2, they depend on N/4.  This should produce correct numbers.  I include a diagram showing where the quartile points are:

```
import math

# 1 2 3 4 5 6 
#   ^  ^  ^
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 
#   ^   ^   ^
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 
#    ^   ^   ^
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#    ^    ^    ^
def quartile_one(x):
    x.sort()
    k = len(x) // 4
    if len(x) % 4 <  2:
        return (x[k-1] + x[k])/2
    else:
        return x[k-1]

def quartile_three(x):
    x.sort()
    k = 3 * len(x) // 4
    if len(x) % 4 <  2:
        return (x[k] + x[k+1])/2
    else:
        return x[k]

x = [1,2,3,4,5]
for z in (6,7,8,9):
    x.append(z)
    print(x)
    print(quartile_one(x))
    print(quartile_three(x))
```

Comment: To add on. If the length of the list is uneven, the median (2nd quartile) is a single number. This means that the first half and second half of the list are of even length and their median (1st and 3rd quartile) falls between two numbers. That's what Tim is fixing above.